# How do I pass in nullable modifiers as out parameters in C#

Tags: c#

Suppose I declare an int with a nullable modifier and I want to pass it as an out parameter to a function. How would I do that?

```
int? count = null;
if(int.TryParse(System.Console.ReadLine(), out count /* illegal */))
...
```

Comment: You can't pass it with `out` to a function that requires an `out int` argument like `int.TryParse`. You can use an `int` and assign that to an `int?` later.

Comment: @Lee How would the function signature look like for a function that accepts a nullable modifier?

Comment: @Lee Oh I see..

Comment: Something like `bool Example(out int? i);` Are you trying to write your own function or call an existing one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int?` is shorthand for [`System.Nullable<int>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1). Adding the `?` to the end of a value type actually declares a different type of variable. The only reason your call to `TryParse` is invalid is because it is expecting an object of type `int`, not `Nullable<int>`.

If you are writing your own method, you can declare your argument types to be whatever you'd like, including `int?`. For example:

```
public void SomeMethod(string input, out int? output)
```

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to C#. Just started studying the language today, sometimes I overthink things.

Comment: Though there isn't really a need for an `out` parameter here (or in general if there is only one result value).

Comment: @ckuri You mean in my example? Agreed. I just wanted to show how it could be done.